# How to set ForeColor for a TreeNode?

Tags: winforms, powershell, treeview, treenode

I created a treeview using powershell code but now i want to change the color of the node during the creation depends of the type of the node.
I tried this =>

```
$newNode = new-object System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode  
$newNode.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

But it's not working, i got an error like "The term 'Color.Blue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet".
Anyone succeed to do it?

Comment: Try $newNode.ForeColor = "Blue"

Comment: I already tried it but it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use a typed color and also have intellisense when writing code, you can use:

```
$newNode.ForeColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::Blue
```

Also, since the color converter can convert color name and R,G,B value to color, you also can use following options:

```
$newNode.ForeColor = "Blue"
$newNode.ForeColor = "0,0,255"
```

Comment: I will try again but it is something like i tried before and it was not working. I will come back to you

Comment: I've tested both of them and they work properly. So let me know if you have any problem applying the solution :)

Comment: Good to hear that!