# How Can I set a label's background transparent in PowerShell?

Tags: .net, winforms, powershell

I have problems to set a `System.Winfows.Forms.Label` background to transparent.

In C# it's easy:

```cs
this.label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
```

However in my PowerShell GUI I can't acchieve the same result. I tried many variants, but none worked out:

```bsh
$my_label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$my_label.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName("Transparent")
```

or

```bsh
$my_color = New-Object System.Drawing.Color.Transparent
$my_label.BackColor = $my_color
```

In C# you can overtake those samples and the resulting label's background becomes transparent. In PowerShell, however, every attempt resulted in different errors.

Haven't I paid regard to something?

Comment: Those errors being ... *what*?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I can post them if there is a opportunity to change the output into english language quickly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46976318/3110834

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set ForeColor for a TreeNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46975130/how-to-set-forecolor-for-a-treenode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this syntax?

```
$my_label.BackColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromName("Transparent")
```

For a static method such as this, the full name of the class surrounded by brackets, then 2 colons then the method name and parameters in parenthesis (unlike a regular PowerShell method).

Comment: Ahhh thank you very much for explaining, that its because it is a static method. This helps a powershell beginner big time.