# How to use z-index for label in powershell using System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#, powershell

I am trying to overlap a `System.Windows.Forms.Label` to over another `Label` in a Powershell script.
Till now i have not found any working solution in- or outside Stackoverflow. Also the solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641768/how-can-i-set-a-labels-background-transparent-in-powershell) using transparancy does not work for me.

What i want to accomplish can be best demonstrated by the Powershell script below.
A dot should be placed on top the 'Hi Mum!' label. Currenly the dot is partially overlayed by the 'Hi Mum!` label, though the dot has been brought to the front.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$FONT_WINGD = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Wingdings", 18)
$FONT_LARGE_BOLD = [System.Drawing.Font]::new("Microsoft Sans Serif", 18, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)

$MyForm                     = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$MyForm.BackColor           = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(200,20, 20)


$MyLabel                    = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$MyLabel.Text               = "HI Mum !" 
$MyLabel.Font               = $FONT_LARGE_BOLD
$MyLabel.width              = 150
$MyLabel.height             = 24
$MyLabel.location           = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(40,20)
#$MyLabel.BackColor             = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromName("Transparent")
$MyLabel.BackColor          = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromName("Green")
$MyLabel.SendToBack()

$Dot                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Dot.text                   = [System.Char]::ConvertFromUtf32(0x25CF);
$Dot.ForeColor              = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(155, 0, 79)
#$Dot.BackColor             = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromName("Transparent")
$Dot.BackColor          = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromName("Blue")
$Dot.width                  = 15
$Dot.height                 = 15
$Dot.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(56,4)
$Dot.Font                   = $FONT_WINGD
$Dot.BringToFront()


$MyForm.controls.AddRange(@($MyLabel,$Dot))

$MyForm.ShowDialog()
```

[image]

Comment: Great [MRE], thanks for that

Comment: This really sucks. I tried adding them individually, calling BringToFront()/SendToBack() in different order and after putting them onto the form, assigning a Z-Index - nothing works.

Comment: Which powershell version do you have. Mine is 5.1.19041.1023 Desktop. Build 10.0.19041.1023. Obviously our two versions behave similarly.

Comment: Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1018
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1018
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Once you've added the control to a parent, use the `Controls` property on the parent to [set the "child index"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.setchildindex) (the z-index):

```
# ...
$MyForm.Controls.AddRange(@($MyLabel,$Dot))

$MyForm.Controls.SetChildIndex($MyLabel, 2)
$Dot.Controls.SetChildIndex($Dot, 1)
```

You could create a simple function to resolve the parent and set the index like so:

```
function Set-WinFormControlZIndex
{
  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [System.Windows.Forms.Control]$Control,

    [int]$Index = -1
  )

  if($Control.Parent -is [System.Windows.Forms.Control]){
    $Control.Parent.Controls.SetChildIndex($Control, $Index)
  }
}
```

Then use like this:

```
# ...
$MyForm.Controls.AddRange(@($MyLabel,$Dot))

Set-WinFormControlZIndex $Dot 1
Set-WinFormControlZIndex $MyLabel 2
```

Comment: Okay, but the result still looks the same. is it the powershell version?

Comment: @ThomasWeller Did you set the index of the `$Dot` to something lower than the index value of `$MyLabel`? Works perfectly fine in 5.1 for me

Comment: $Dot gets 1, $MyLabel 2. I have PowerShell 5.1.19041.1023

Comment: When setting childindex i do get ` Exception calling "SetChildIndex" with "2" argument(s):` Loosly translated details; Underlying item is not a underlying control element of this upper element.

Does run now without execeptions after changing `$Dot.Controls.SetChildIndex($Dot, 1)`  to  `$MyForm.Controls.SetChildIndex($Dot, 1)`.

But results are the same for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me (also PowerShell 5.1) this works:

move `$MyLabel.SendToBack()` and `$Dot.BringToFront()` **AFTER** adding these controls to the form:

```
$MyForm.Controls.AddRange(@($MyLabel,$Dot))
$MyLabel.SendToBack()
$Dot.BringToFront()
```

OR

Remove `$MyLabel.SendToBack()` and `$Dot.BringToFront()` from your code and do

```
$MyForm.Controls.AddRange(@($MyLabel,$Dot))
$MyForm.Controls.SetChildIndex($Dot, 1)
$MyForm.Controls.SetChildIndex($MyLabel, 2)
```

---

The above works, but what the code is missing is to set the `.TextAlign` property on the label that holds the dot. Because of that, the dot is actually cut off in that small label size.

Either set `$Dot.Width` and `$Dot.Height` to larger pixel sizes so the dot will actually fit, or do

```
$Dot.TextAlign = 'MiddleCenter'
# and after adding to the Forms Control collection, 
$MyForm.Controls.AddRange(@($MyLabel,$Dot))
$Dot.BringToFront()
```

(To make the picture clearer, I have set the dot character to be yellow and set the .Location to `(58,8)`)

[image]

Comment: Tried both options, the 'dot' is still partly behind the MyLabel. Added a sample screenshot to my question. Does not change when applying any of the solutions.

Comment: @pcvnes Please see my edit. It explains the code _does_ work, but because the dot does not fit the label it only looks like it is still behind the other label..